# Connect appscript to database

Tags: google-apps-script

I have this project on appscript where all the data are stored in gsheet. Now we have a db which is microsoft sql azure management, how will I transfer all the data of my appscript to that database?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the way to connect to external databases is JDBC.  Making the connection is often the most difficult  part of the process of interacting with an external database.

Most users find the interface slow and not very efficient.

- [JDBC](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc)